# Trying to read multipart/form-data in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, next.js

I am learning NextJS/Django. I am trying to send some FormData to my Django back end. It contains some strings and an image file. But, I am getting the following error:

`django.http.multipartparser.MultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None`

Form:

```
<form
      className={styles.formContainer}
      method="post"
      encType="multipart/form-data"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="email" className={styles.text}>
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          className="form-control"
          id="email"
          aria-describedby="emailHelp"
          placeholder="Change email here"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="image" className={styles.text}>
          Image
        </label>
        <input
          type="file"
          className="form-control"
          id="image"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={(e) => setImageLink(e.target.files[0])}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="description" className={styles.text}>
          Description
        </label>
        <textarea
          className="form-control"
          id="description"
          rows="5"
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        style={{ marginTop: "7px" }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
```

Submit Button:

```
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("userID", loggedInID);
    data.append("email", email);
    data.append("description", description);
    data.append("image", imageLink);

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/edit_profile/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
      },
      credentials: "include",
      body: data,
    }).then((response) => response);

  }
```

Django View:

```
    @parser_classes([FormParser, MultiPartParser])
    @csrf_exempt
    def editProfileView(request):
        print(request.data)


    return JsonResponse({})
```

The Django view is currently unfinished, as I cannot read the data in the sent FormData. Any help is appreciated.